# How to Increase Logcat Message length?

Tags: android

I wanted to display a long url in logcat. But it is breaked and is limited to about 4063 charcters? 
Is there any option to increase Message length of logcat?

Comment: If you're using a url thats longer than 4063 characters, you're doing something terribly wrong.

Comment: already changed that to post method. but i need to known why message length  is limited to about 4063 characters in logcat. Forget url and just think as a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use DDMS, which is one option..Copy from a DDMS to any text editor..See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1997904/how-can-i-see-long-texts-msg-in-logcat)