# How I get the html all source?

Tags: android, string, inputstream, bufferedreader

I mean that I use below code to get html source from url. But it does not contain all source.Buffersize is problem or string size problem?

```
HttpURLConnection connection; 
            OutputStreamWriter request = null; 

                 URL url = null;    
                 String response = null;          
                 String parameters = "aranan="+et.getText();    

                 try 
                 { 
                     url = new URL("http://www.fragmanfan.com/arama.asp"); 
                     connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); 
                     connection.setDoOutput(true); 
                     connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); 

                     request = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream()); 
                     request.write(parameters); 
                     request.flush();             
                     String line = "";                
                     InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()); 
                     BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(isr); 
                     StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); 
                     while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) 
                     { 
                         sb.append(line + "\n"); 
                     } 
                     // Response from server after login process will be stored in response variable.                 
                     response = sb.toString(); 
                     // You can perform UI operations here 
                     browser.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, response,"text/html", "UTF-8", null); 

                     isr.close(); 
                     reader.close(); 

                 } 
                 catch(IOException e) 
                 { 
                     // Error 
                 } 




        } 
    });
```

I try some things like  `BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(isr,8192);` 
But it does not work.

Comment: have you tried whether you are getting the  source using normal stand alone java application using the same url?

Comment: no. not in java . But the ı do not get the full html page source.Only 892 words nearly.String size problem? or buffer? how can ı solve this?

Comment: try to run the same logic in java first.so you can easily figure out what is going on.If that worked in java, it should work in android as well

Comment: how can ı try. it is same code? it works on android but it does  not contain all html source:(

Comment: we use double instead of int . so is there anything which size bigger than string I use isntead of string.

Comment: I think it is not size problem. but why the page do not get all html source .I do not understand

Comment: What do you want to do with the HTML source once you have it?

Comment: I edit it.I want to get www.example.com html source and I edit it and then I load this html in my webview. because of this I want to get full source but response is only one piece pf source

Comment: what I would suggest is run your application as stand alone java application.Make sure is there any problem in your URL.Also, change that URL to a different one and loads it in android and compare the results.Size cannot be the issue here

Comment: Yes I do that.But different url ,same result. size is not problem.But what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a WebRequest class.
Than make your request and get response.
I tried that website, it works.

```
WebRequest response = new WebRequest("http://www.fragmanfan.com/arama.asp?aranan=kurtlar", PostType.GET);
String htmltext = response.Get();
browser.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, htmltext, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```

**WebRequest.class**

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.CookieStore;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.client.protocol.ClientContext;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicCookieStore;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.protocol.BasicHttpContext;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext;

public class WebRequest {
  public enum PostType{
    GET, POST;
  }

  public String _url;
  public String response = "";
  public PostType _postType;
  CookieStore _cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();

  public WebRequest(String url) {
    _url = url;
    _postType = PostType.POST;
  }

  public WebRequest(String url, CookieStore cookieStore) {
    _url = url;
    _cookieStore = cookieStore;
    _postType = PostType.POST;
  }

  public WebRequest(String url, PostType postType) {
    _url = url;
    _postType = postType;
  }

  public String Get() {
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

    try {
      // Create local HTTP context
      HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();

      // Bind custom cookie store to the local context
      localContext.setAttribute(ClientContext.COOKIE_STORE, _cookieStore);

      HttpResponse httpresponse;
      if (_postType == PostType.POST)
      {
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(_url);
        httpresponse = httpclient.execute(httppost, localContext);
      }
      else
      {
        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(_url);
        httpresponse = httpclient.execute(httpget, localContext);
      }

      StringBuilder responseString = inputStreamToString(httpresponse.getEntity().getContent());

      response = responseString.toString();
    }
    catch (UnknownHostException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
      // When HttpClient instance is no longer needed,
      // shut down the connection manager to ensure
      // immediate deallocation of all system resources
      httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
    }

    return response;
  }

  private StringBuilder inputStreamToString(InputStream is) throws IOException {
    String line = "";
    StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();

    // Wrap a BufferedReader around the InputStream
    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,Charset.forName("iso-8859-9")));
    // Read response until the end
    while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
      total.append(line);
    }

    // Return full string
    return total;
  }
}
```

Comment: but it stil doen not contain all source page. Try   WebRequest response = new WebRequest("http://www.fragmanfan.com/fan/film-1", PostType.GET);  this and you see cant see the all page

Comment: I tried and I am seeing whole page? Why do you think you are getting partial page? Here is the screen shot of footer of page that I see on WebView. http://img14.imageshack.us/img14/573/resim2cf.png

Comment: Also  I debug logged last 100 characters of page return from request. You can see that </html> tag which is end of page. Are you trying to log.d whole page because you can't see that big of text data on log console window, It crops after a while. But If you attach response to a webview you can use it.

Log.d("", "" + htmltext.substring(htmltext.length()-100));


D/        (  351): t></a></font></td>
</tr>                                   </table>
</div>                          </td>                   </tr>           </table>
        </div></body></html>`

Comment: :( pffff :( why I dont have it. I see in your code you success it but when I am try it , only one part of source...:( why why why

Comment: How/why do you think you are getting part of source code? can you post a screen shot? and also log last 100 charatcers of response and see where it crops like this: Log.d("", htmltext.substring(htmltext.length()-100));

Comment: thanks for answering. firstly sorry.always I debug and control htmltext(string variable) and I see it it does not contain all source but when I look the result I am shock . Alla page seen.But when I controlled in debug it does not contain why? I want to edit htmltext but it is giving error because it does not contain all source :(

Comment: editing and getting error is completetly different problem and question I think. With this code, you can get whole source code and If you bind to a webview you can completely see html page. If you want to manipulate source and getting error you might  doing something wrong while parsing. I think you need to open another queestion with that problem and with the error you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

I had some problem.

I  used  `Log.i("tag", html)`
But logger has a max lenght of message. And my html text was clipped.
There are two solutions:

1. split your html into small pieces
2. Make bigger size of max lenght of message  as in this post: 
   [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8888654/android-set-max-length-of-logcat-messages)