# Android jsoup doesnt get complete HTML document

Tags: android, jsoup, document

I have a problem with jsoup library, when I request an URL with post method I can't download complete HTML document, I get only half the document.
how can I solve this. 
Thanks in advance.

```
Thread hilo = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            String url = "http://correos.es/comun/CodigosPostales/1010_s-CodPostal.asp";
                            Map<String, String> mapa = new HashMap<String, String>();
                            mapa.put("LlamarWebService", "false");
                            mapa.put("Prueba", "");
                            mapa.put("Ejecutando", "Direcciones");
                            mapa.put("Formu1", "FormLoc");
                            mapa.put("Formu2", "FormProvin");
                            mapa.put("CodPostal", numero);

                            String userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1312.60 Safari/537.17";
                            Connection conn = Jsoup.connect(url).data(mapa).userAgent(userAgent);
                            Document doc = conn.post();
                            Elements elemento = doc.select("div.txtNormal");
                            Log.e("", elemento.toString());

                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            Log.e("Error", e.toString());
                        }
                    }
                });
                hilo.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you write the html code inside Eclipse Logcat ? It's possible that you see only a part of the text because Eclipse limits the length of the text shown. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8888654/android-set-max-length-of-logcat-messages) might help you.

Gordak

Comment: Logcat is only for testing, but the document selected is null.