# How to print to the console in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, mobile, development-environment, android-studio

I just downloaded Android Studio for Linux from: 
http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html

I'm wondering how to print to the console?

Neither `System.out.print(...)` nor `Log.e(...)` from `android.util.Log` seem to work.

Comment: Those should "print" to LogCat, just as they do on Eclipse.

Comment: You can also see print statements in `Run` window as I answered here.. https://stackoverflow.com/a/46843640/2462531

Answer (score 234, accepted):

Run your application in **debug** *mode* by clicking on

[image]

in the upper menu of Android Studio.

In the bottom status bar, click `5: Debug` button, next to the `4: Run` button.

Now you should select the `Logcat` console.

In search box, you can type the *tag* of your message, and your message should appear, like in the following picture (where the tag is `CREATION`):

[image]

Check [this article](https://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-studio.html) for more information.

Answer (score 207):

Android has its own method of printing messages (called [`logs`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html)) to the console, known as the `LogCat`.

When you want to print something to the `LogCat`, you use a `Log` object, and specify the category of message.

The main options are:

- DEBUG: `Log.d`
- ERROR: `Log.e`
- INFO: `Log.i`
- VERBOSE: `Log.v`
- WARN: `Log.w`

You print a message by using a `Log` statement in your code, like the following example:

```
Log.d("myTag", "This is my message");
```

Within Android Studio, you can search for log messages labelled `myTag` to easily find the message in the `LogCat`. You can also choose to filter logs by category, such as "Debug" or "Warn".

Comment: What could be causing the following error when trying to use Log? `Could not get unknown property 'Log' for object of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.api.LibraryVariantImpl.`

Comment: My personal favorite is `Log.wtf` (What a Terrible Failure) :D

Comment: Does not work: `error: cannot find symbol variable log.`

Comment: To view this log, go to `Run` tab in bottom left of Android Studio.

Answer (score 27):

### Android Studio 3.0 and earlier:

If the other solutions don't work, you can always see the output in the ***[Android Monitor](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/monitor)***.

---

[image: android studio screen shot]

---

Make sure to set your filter to ***Show only selected application*** or create a custom filter.

[image]

Comment: My mistake was not properly setting the top 2 drop-down boxes in Android Monitor (having multiple emulators running I assumed the last running emulator and app would be auto selected - not so).

Comment: How to open the Android Monitor?

Answer (score 17):

You can see the `println()` statements in the `Run` window of Android Studio.

See detailed answer with screenshot [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46843640/2462531).

Answer (score 2):

Be careful when using [Logcat](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat), it will truncate your message after ~4,076 bytes which can cause a lot of headache if you're printing out large amounts of data.

To get around this you have to write a function that will break it up into multiple parts [like so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8888654/android-set-max-length-of-logcat-messages).

Answer (score 2):

In kotlin, you can use logcat to print in console.

Logcat is made of 2 parameters: one is Tag and second is string (that you want to print).

Their are mainly 5 types of Logcat

1. **Error Level**: Something went seriously wrong

   Log.e(TAG, "ERROR")
2. **Warn Level**: Less severe than an error but still neec be fixed

   Log.w(TAG, "WARN")
3. **Info Level**: Used we need to provide information

   Log.i(TAG, "INFO")
4. **Debug Level**: Information that may be useful when  addressing an issue

   Log.d(TAG, "DEBUG")
5. **Verbose Level**: Least specific log level

   Log.v(TAG, "VERBOSE")

Error log in red, warn log in blue and other three in black color.

[image: Different Color of Logcat]

Comment: Thank you, I am searching for the error log in Kotlin, and it is the same.

Answer (score 1):

If your app is launched from device, not IDE, you can do later in menu: `Run` - `Attach Debugger to Android Process`.

This can be useful when debugging notifications on closed application.

Answer (score 1):

I had solve the issue by revoking my USB debugging authorizations.

To Revoke,

Go to **Device Settings > Enable Developer Options > Revoke USB debugging authorizations**