# How to log results to the console in android studio

Tags: javascript, android

i have just made a small test case in my android studio project , see code below :

```
public class MainActivityTest extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<MainActivity> {

    MainActivity activity;



    public MainActivityTest() {
        super(MainActivity.class);
    }

    @Override
    protected void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
        activity = getActivity();
    }

    public void testMainActivity() {
        TextView textView = (TextView) activity.findViewById(R.id.hello_world);
        Log.d(textView);
        assertNotNull(textView);
    }
}
```

now all i wanted to do was log the value of `textView` to the console , so i referred the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-log.html) and saw that i could `console.log()` results(just like in javascript) using `Log.d(testView);` .

but the problem is the below line in my code :

`Log.d(testView);` , causes an error , when i hover over `Log` i get the message saying "cannot resolve symbol Log" .

so my question is how do i log results to the console in android studio .

I refered to **[THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16780294/how-to-print-to-the-console-in-android-studio)** question too but i'am still stuck.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It saying this because there is no `Log.d(TextView textView)` method. Here is a doc https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html.
But there is a `Log.d(String tag, String message)` method. Then call it like

```
Log.d("Message tag",textView.getText().toString());
```

Comment: worked , but how do i see it in the console now , do i have to run something ?

Comment: Select `Android` in bottom menu in Android Studio and click `logcat` then. Select proper filter and it should be visible.

Comment: did that , see the screen shot here , i still can't see anything in the log http://i.imgur.com/xoUa4q6.jpg

Comment: You can see these red text saying no application and no device selected. When you connect something and run app, logcat should fulfill.

Comment: so logcat needs a external device to run ?

Answer (score 3):

`Log.d("TAG", "Message");`

1) Use capital letter as `Log` not `log`
2) It has two params (or three), not just one

You can log textview value by

```
TextView textView = (TextView) activity.findViewById(R.id.hello_world);
Log.d("TAG", textView.getText().toString());
```

Answer (score 2):

Log is a part of `android.util.Log`. So you must first import this.

Log uses a tag as it's first parameter, and an output string as it's second. For example:

```
private static final String TAG = "MyActivity";
Log.d(TAG, "index=" + i);
```

You could also do `System.out.println("My string here");`

But please note that there is an error in your code. Log requires a string value, which can be fetched using `testView.getText().toString()` instead of `testView`

Answer (score 1):

Did you import it?

```
import android.util.Log
```

And according to the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html) you have to put at least 2 strings to the function, a TAG and a message:

```
log.d("MainActivityTest", textView.getText());
```

Comment: worked , but how do i see it in the console now , do i have to run something ?