# print on console in android studio

Tags: android

I want to know where the output of System.out.printf will be shown in Android Studio

```
package com.example.kakashi.gesture1;

import android.support.v4.view.MotionEventCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  }

  public void printSamples(MotionEvent event){
    int historySize = event.getHistorySize();
    int pointerCount = event.getPointerCount();
    for (int i=0;i<historySize;i++) {
      System.out.printf("At time %d",event.getHistoricalEventTime(i));
      for (int p=0;p<pointerCount;p++){
        System.out.printf("pointer %d ( %f,  %f                                                                             )",event.getPointerId(p),event.getX(p),event.getY(p));
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Check the logcat (Android Monitor)
Also i suggest use the `Log` class for this purpose.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to print to the console in Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16780294/how-to-print-to-the-console-in-android-studio)

Answer (score 27):

You can see the `println` statements in `Run` window as shown below screenshot. so you can see the prinln statements in that window.

For example if I wanna see Strings which are in for loop then:

[image]

Comment: I am going to up vote because it seems that this is actually the only answer that answers this question. I have a need to print out to the console since I am trying to parse log files on a rooted device. Logging the messages that I see in Logcat only make the buffer fill up faster.

Answer (score 3):

In the bottom of Android Studio IDE there is **Android Monitor**. Click it.

Then you can check your `System.out.printf` output in logcat tab there. Play around with list of `Debug`, `Error`, `Info`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

if you are using `System.out.printf` it will be shown in android studio console but if you are using `Log.e(...)` or etc it will be shown in logcat.