# why does my data not come out?

Tags: php, android, android-studio

```
public class Config {
    public static final String DATA_URL = "http://192.168.1.2/retrieveone.php?id=";
    public static final String KEY_NAME = "BusinessName";
    public static final String KEY_AmountTotal = "AmountTotal";
    public static final String KEY_RT = "RequiredTotal";
    public static final String KEY_MT = "MaxTotal";
    public static final String JSON_ARRAY = "result";
}
```

This is my class file .

```
  private void getData(){
        String id = TempItem.toString().trim();
        if (id.equals("")) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter an id", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }


        String url = Config.DATA_URL+TempItem.toString().trim();

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET,url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {

                showJSON(response);
            }
        },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(KPDetails.this,error.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        error.printStackTrace();
                    }
                });
        int socketTimeout =50000;//5 seconds - change to what you want
        RetryPolicy policy = new DefaultRetryPolicy(socketTimeout, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT);
        stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(policy);
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }
 private void showJSON(String response){
        String name="";
        String AmountTotal="";
        String RequiredTotal = "";
        String MaxTotal = "";
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
            JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray(Config.JSON_ARRAY);
            JSONObject stallsData = result.getJSONObject(0);
            name = stallsData.getString(Config.KEY_NAME);
            AmountTotal = stallsData.getString(Config.KEY_AmountTotal);
            MaxTotal = stallsData.getString(Config.KEY_MT);
            RequiredTotal = stallsData.getString(Config.KEY_RT);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Stall.setText("Name:\t"+name+"\nAmountTotal:\t" +AmountTotal+ "\nMaxTotal:\t"+ MaxTotal);
    }
```

This is my constructor to get data from mysql daatabase. However, I managed to get the setText but not the value of the strings in config.

This is my php file.

```
?php 


if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='GET'){

 $id  = $_GET['id'];

 require_once('conn.php');

 $sql = "SELECT * FROM business WHERE BusinessID='".$id."'";

 $r = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

 $res = mysqli_fetch_array($r);

 $result = array();

 array_push($result,array(
 "BusinessName"=>$res['BusinessName'],
 "AmountTotal"=>$res['AmountTotal'],
 "RequiredTotal"=>$res['RequiredTotal'],
"MaxTotal"=>$res['MaxTotal']
 )
 );

 echo json_encode(array("result"=>$result));

 mysqli_close($conn);

}
```

"http://localhost/retrieveone.php?id=1" works perfectly fine but the value just does not show up in my setText.
I am a beginner in Android Studio. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Edit:

This is my error . Value connection of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Comment: can you show the output of your JSONObject?

Comment: @Mahdi.Pishguy you taged wrong person i am not the one who posted the question:)

Comment: @HahaHehe your parsed json is not correct please add `Log.e("error ",e.getMessage())` after `e.printStackTrace();` and run again app to see what happen on Logcat

Comment: @HemantSangle i'm sorry sir, thanks

Comment: Value connection of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Answer (score 0):

first declare a json array with response text and then make a JSONObject.
try this..

```
   try {
        JSONArray result = new JSONArray(response);
        JSONObject stallsData = result.getJSONObject(0);
        name = stallsData.getString(Config.KEY_NAME);
        AmountTotal = stallsData.getString(Config.KEY_AmountTotal);
        MaxTotal = stallsData.getString(Config.KEY_MT);
        RequiredTotal = stallsData.getString(Config.KEY_RT);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you import/include the class 'Config' file , before accessing it ?

And please put your code in try/catch block and output the exception for more information.

Comment: Value connection of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Comment: Reason is some un-wanted characters was added while compose the String  'response'. please format it properly.  Can output the response string ?? will be helpful

Comment: how do I do that by the way ? I am a beginner in Android Studio and have no idea how to output the response string. Thanks in advance

Comment: refer to this link [here] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16780294/how-to-print-to-the-console-in-android-studio

Comment: {"result":[{"BusinessName":"KachangPuteh","AmountTotal":"100","RequiredTotal":"200","MaxTotal":"500"}]}

Comment: great! this json string got some hidden values which is causing the issue, this is how it looks {"result":[{"BusinessName":"KachangPuteh","AmountTotal":"100&zwnj;&#8203;","RequiredTotal":"2&zwnj;&#8203;00","MaxTotal":"500"&zwnj;&#8203;}]}, you can validate your json  [here](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/)

Comment: and how would I solve it? I have tried  JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
          String results= jsonObject.getString(Config.JSON_ARRAY);
            JSONArray result = new JSONArray(results);

Comment: quick fix would be to replace &zwnj; and &#8203; with empty string and then try to convert to JSON object

Comment: And how do I do that? Would be helpful if code is given as I do not know how to do it

Comment: `$str = json_encode(array("result"=>$result));
$str=str_replace('&#8203;','',$str);
$str=str_replace('&zwnj;','',$str);
echo $srt;`

in you php file before echoing the output

Comment: any luck @HahaHehe ??

Comment: No but I did a different way

Comment: how, can you post your answer please ?

Comment: As in instead of using volley i just used http which worked