# How to increase transport.dump size from 256 bytes to 512 or more bytes in KSOAP2?

Tags: android, xml, xml-parsing, xmlhttprequest, android-ksoap2

I have HttpTransportSE object from KSOAP2 library.
I want to dump response file which may contains mote then simple **9697 character**.
currently i am doing it by making transport.

```
transport.debug = true;
System.out.println("Response ----------"+transport.responseDump);
```

But it gives me half response with **...** at last.

In its internal coding structure i found that it is using 256 bytes for creating and destroying it's **responseDump** like shown below:

```
package org.ksoap2.transport;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.Proxy;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.List;
import org.ksoap2.HeaderProperty;
import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException;

public class HttpTransportSE extends Transport
{
  private ServiceConnection connection;

  public HttpTransportSE(String url)
  {
    super(null, url);
  }

  public HttpTransportSE(Proxy proxy, String url)
  {
    super(proxy, url);
  }

  public HttpTransportSE(String url, int timeout)
  {
    super(url, timeout);
  }

  public HttpTransportSE(Proxy proxy, String url, int timeout) {
    super(proxy, url, timeout);
  }

  public void call(String soapAction, SoapEnvelope envelope)
    throws IOException, XmlPullParserException
  {
    call(soapAction, envelope, null);
  }

  public List call(String soapAction, SoapEnvelope envelope, List headers)
    throws IOException, XmlPullParserException
  {
    if (soapAction == null) {
      soapAction = "\"\"";
    }
    byte[] requestData = createRequestData(envelope);

    this.requestDump = (this.debug ? new String(requestData) : null);
    this.responseDump = null;

    this.connection = getServiceConnection();

    this.connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "kSOAP/2.0");

    if (envelope.version != 120) {
      this.connection.setRequestProperty("SOAPAction", soapAction);
    }
    this.connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/xml");
    this.connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "close");
    this.connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "" + requestData.length);

    if (headers != null) {
      for (int i = 0; i < headers.size(); i++) {
        HeaderProperty hp = (HeaderProperty)headers.get(i);
        this.connection.setRequestProperty(hp.getKey(), hp.getValue()); }  } 
this.connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
    this.connection.connect();

    OutputStream os = this.connection.openOutputStream();

    os.write(requestData, 0, requestData.length);
    os.flush();
    os.close();
    requestData = null;

    List retHeaders = null;
    InputStream is;
    try { this.connection.connect();
      is = this.connection.openInputStream();
      retHeaders = this.connection.getResponseProperties();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      is = this.connection.getErrorStream();

      if (is == null) {
        this.connection.disconnect();
        throw e;
      }
    }

    if (this.debug) {
      ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
      byte[] buf = new byte[256];
      while (true)
      {
        int rd = is.read(buf, 0, 256);
        if (rd == -1)
          break;
        bos.write(buf, 0, rd);
      }

      bos.flush();
      buf = bos.toByteArray();
      this.responseDump = new String(buf);
      is.close();
      is = new ByteArrayInputStream(buf);
    }

    parseResponse(envelope, is);
    return retHeaders;
  }

  public ServiceConnection getConnection() {
    return (ServiceConnectionSE)this.connection;
  }

  protected ServiceConnection getServiceConnection() throws IOException {
    return new ServiceConnectionSE(this.proxy, this.url, this.timeout);
  }

  public String getHost()
  {
    String retVal = null;
    try
    {
      retVal = new URL(this.url).getHost();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return retVal;
  }

  public int getPort()
  {
    int retVal = -1;
    try
    {
      retVal = new URL(this.url).getPort();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return retVal;
  }

  public String getPath()
  {
    String retVal = null;
    try
    {
      retVal = new URL(this.url).getPath();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return retVal;
  }
}
```

You found that its only

**int rd = is.read(buf, 0, 256);**

**So, is there any options to increase responseDump size?**

Comment: Answer is:                                                         if (transport.debug) {
        
byte[] is = transport.responseDump.getBytes();
String path="/mnt/sdcard/appData/";
File file = new File(path+"responseDump.xml");
if (!file.exists()) {
file.createNewFile();
}
BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));
bos.write(is);
bos.flush();
bos.close();
}                                                                     Thanks esentsov.

Answer (score 1):

There is no limitation in ksoap, but it is in logcat. Logcat doesn't print long strings, so write in a file or write piece by piece in the log.

Comment: If you see this internal code of ksoap2 its only taking 256 bytes only. so even if i am trying to write byte by byte its not complete responseDump. Still ii you think its possible kindly response with solution. And again thanks!.

Comment: It reads an input stream in a cycle piece by piece with buffer size 256 bytes, not only the first 256 bytes.

Comment: [check this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8888654/android-set-max-length-of-logcat-messages)

Answer (score 0):

```
if (transport.debug) 
{ 
byte[] is = transport.responseDump.getBytes(); 
String path="/mnt/sdcard/appData/"; 
File file = new File(path+"responseDump.xml"); 
if (!file.exists()) 
{ 
file.createNewFile();
}
BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file)); bos.write(is); bos.flush(); bos.close(); 
}
```