# Android logcat stops midline

Tags: java, android, logcat

I am trying to debug a vendor's Android app that we're modifying to suit our needs so it's not our code and the issue isn't priority enough for them to fix. It's crashing on a Galaxy Tab 10.1 (runs fine on emulators and a Galaxy Nexus), but whenever the app crashes, I can never get a complete stack trace. It always gets cut off in the middle of the line: `at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native M`. Notice how it even stops mid-word.

I've also grabbed the log files directly from the device and they show the same cut off.

I can see that it has something to do with `GradesListAdapter.getView`. Debugging and stepping into that line leads to Android system code.

What could be causing Android to stop mid-line in its output? Are there other ways to debug an app that might give better results?

---

```
01-10 11:08:29.855    2033-2033/ E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class <unknown>
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:660)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
            at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:371)
            at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:362)
            at com.ellucian.mobile.android.grades.GradesListAdapter.getView(GradesListAdapter.java:99)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2472)
            at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1775)
            at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:678)
            at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:739)
            at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1628)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2307)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14072)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4657)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1655)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1513)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1426)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14072)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4657)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onLayout(ViewPager.java:1589)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14072)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4657)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1655)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1513)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1426)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14072)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4657)
            at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:678)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14072)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4657)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14072)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4657)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1655)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1513)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1426)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14072)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4657)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14072)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4657)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2004)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1825)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1120)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4604)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)
            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native M

01-10 11:08:29.905    2033-2037/ D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 388K, 12% free 8181K/9223K, paused 11ms+14ms, total 47ms
01-10 11:08:29.975    2141-2214/? E/android.os.Debug﹕ !@Dumpstate > dumpstate -k -t -z -d -o /data/log/dumpstate_app_error
01-10 11:08:29.985    3361-3361/? I/dumpstate﹕ begin
```

Comment: Also: how are you logging your exceptions? Normally, `android.util.Log.e(TAG, message, exception);` will log the stacktrace one line at a time and that prevents this problem. If you try to log the trace in one message, you'll hit the ~4k buffersize limit.

Comment: I run the debugger in Eclipse and haven't added any particular code to log the errors.

The question then is, How do you log the stacktrace one line at a time then?

Answer (score 0):

As noted in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8899735/1676363), the size of a single logcat message is ~4076 bytes.

In your case, the relevant lines are already in the logcat output:

> android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:371) at
>   android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:362) at
>   com.ellucian.mobile.android.grades.GradesListAdapter.getView(GradesListAdapter.java:99)

Showing that the layout you've used for your GradesListAdapter is the source of the problem.

Comment: Yes, that I know. But what exactly is the problem? There should be two Caused By entries that shows more information as to the exact cause.