# Jsoup.connect().get() takes only part of html file on Android

Tags: java, android, parsing, jsoup

So, I try to parse Wikipedia, and my code works well at computer. 
All, what I changed - .connect().get is in AsyncTask, but I get only part of html file (no "body", only half of second "script" in "title") and I can't understand why.
This is my code example for Android.

```
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect(params[0]).get();
            return doc.toString();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            //...
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

And this is simple.

```
String url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protectorate";
    Document doc = null;
    try {
        doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        //...
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I checked, params[0] is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protectorate, here's no mistake. 
If you need some extra information, I will give it, of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logcat fools us here, since it shortens the message (I assume you checked your string with logcat? See [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8888654/android-set-max-length-of-logcat-messages))

If you split your result string into chunks, you will see that the whole page was loaded. Try adding something like this `logAll` function to your AsyncTask class to see the full output:

```
private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

    Document doc = null;

    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        try {
            doc = Jsoup.connect(params[0]).get();
            return doc.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return doc.toString();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        logAll("async",doc.toString());
    }

    void logAll(String TAG, String longString) {

        int splitSize = 300;

        if (longString.length() > splitSize) {
            int index = 0;
            while (index < longString.length()-splitSize) {
                Log.e(TAG, longString.substring(index, index + splitSize));
                index += splitSize;
            }
            Log.e(TAG, longString.substring(index, longString.length()));
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, longString.toString());
        }
    }
}
```