# How to split a string containing non ascii characters based on the byte size limit?

Tags: java, unicode, utf-8, byte, bytearrayoutputstream

How to split a string containing non ascii characters based on the byte size limit? 
I want to split the below string and add to a List and the split is based on the size limit (e.g) 3 bytes.

The problem here is extended ascii char takes 2 characters and after split the data become junk as shown in the actual output.

what I want is the expected output as given below, its ok to write only 2 bytes, if we come across non-ascii char. Please let me know how to resolve it. 
**Problem:**

```
String words = "Hello woræd  æåéøòôóâ";
        List<String> payloads = new ArrayList<>();
        try( ByteArrayOutputStream outStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();) {
            byte[] chars = words.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
             for (byte ch: chars) {
                 outStream.write(ch);
                 if (outStream.size() >= 3) {
                     String s = outStream.toString("UTF-8");
                     payloads.add(s);
                     outStream.flush();
                     outStream.reset();
                 }
             }
            payloads.add(outStream.toString("UTF-8"));
            outStream.flush();
            System.out.println(payloads);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

**Actual Output:** [Hel, lo , wor, æd,   �, �å, é�, �ò, ô�, �â, ]

**Expected output:** [Hel, lo , wor, æd,  ,æ, å, é, ø, ò, ô, ó, â]  ]

Comment: What do you want to happen to a character that takes four bytes?

Comment: What I mentioned here is the core problem to resolve the actual problem. 
Think of a table with dynamic row with variable columns where in each column length max size is 64KB. This table row has to be populated from a string whos length can be more than 64KB. Add a dynamic column in the row when it exceeds 64kb, if there comes a 2 or 4 byte char at the time of the split,  you can write the value < 64kb in the slot, and moving the special char to next slot

Comment: Loop through the string codepoint by codepoint (using `String.codePointAt` and `Character.charCount`), convert each one to UTF-8 bytes, and check the byte count before writing the bytes to the ByteArrayOutputStream.  By the way, the `flush` and `close` methods of ByteArrayOutputStream do nothing, so there is no point in calling flush() and no point in using a try-with-resources statement.

Answer (score 1):

It's UTF-8.  UTF-8 is designed so that you can easlly detect character boundaries.

So: convert String to UTF-8 bytes.

Then backtrack until the first excluded byte is a legitimate 'first byte', i.e. **not** 10xxxxxx.  You are now positioned at a character boundary.

Comment: I refer this https://stackoverflow.com/a/48870243/8887205 to resolve my problem. I appreciate others for providing their comments and helping here