# Doing a post with flutter, header is truncated at 1024byte with android

Tags: android, flutter

I've done this code in flutter that do a POST on an API

```
  ...
  String url = 'http://localhost:8080/backoffice/login';

  final uri = Uri.parse(url);
    
  //encode Map to JSON
  final response = await http.post(uri,headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"});
  Map<String, String> headers = response.headers;

  print(headers['x-auth-token']);
  ...
```

When I run the code with WEB or iOS the x-auth-token is correct. If i run it on Android devices the x-auth-token is truncated at 1024 bytes.

Comment: I am assuming you are referring to the response headers. Did you use some network monitoring tool to see the request/response itself?

Comment: what network monitoring tool can i use with android?

Comment: Proxyman/Charles Proxy are two examples. You could also use Android Studio's App Inspection.

Comment: I try with android studio and the header is truncated at 1024 character

Comment: Flutter requests don't show in proxy apps. Try [Flutter DevTools](https://docs.flutter.dev/tools/devtools/network) to intercept the response. Also, do a `print(headers['x-auth-token'].length)` too and show to us what is the result

Answer (score 1):

You can see only first 1024 characters due to the limits of the `print()` function.
You can use `debugPrint` to log longer texts:

```dart
debugPrint(someSuperLongString, wrapWidth: 2048);
```

See: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/22665#issuecomment-506687219

But, there is also a hard limit of 4096 characters (it includes also `I/flutter` prefix) on Android platform. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74171156/630398

To log even more characters you have to partition the string and log each piece separately.